# Qual a diferença e as vantagens de OpenGL e DirectX e quando usar?

Tags: opengl, directx

Tenho entrado em alguns sites e uns falam bem do OpenGL por ser multiplataforma, outros defendendo o uso do directx devido a ser da microsoft e dizem ser mais fácil de usar, outros falam para ao invés de usar diretamente o OpenGL usar o SDL. Estou começando a ver agora essa parte de programação usando bibliotecas gráficas, queria saber quais as principais diferença entre uma e outra a nível de performance e facilidade de uso e quando é mais indicado o uso de cada uma.

Comment: Dá uma olhadinha neste artigo da Wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_OpenGL_and_Direct3D E depois neste sobre valve: http://www.extremetech.com/gaming/133824-valve-opengl-is-faster-than-directx-even-on-windows Penso que pode te ajudar um pouquinho, esse assunto é um pouco complexo pra responder de forma tão genérica assim.

Comment: @Zanoldor li, são bons mesmo! O OpenGL 4 bater o Directx era coisa que eu nem imagina.

Comment: Olá. Concordo com o @Zanoldor. Também me parece que a sua pergunta está um tanto quanto abrangente. Eu entendo que comparar OpenGL e DirectX faz sentido por ambas serem API's similares para renderização gráfica 2D ou 3D. Mas não sei se cabe incluir SDL e principalmente Unity3D no mesmo "bolo" porque elas fazem bem mais do que isso (e, na verdade, reusam as duas anteriores).

Comment: @LuizVieira OpenGL e Directx eu até que tinha um pouco de noção as outras eu não conheço quase nada mesmo. Talvez tenha ficado realmente muito extenso.

Comment: Tanto a SDL quanto a Unity3D são para o mesmo fim, assim como o OpenGL é para o Directx? Que se for o caso eu desmembro em uma nova pergunta.

Comment: @LuizVieira vocês tem razão, depois que pesquisei um pouco vi que ficaria realmente muito extensa uma boa explicação e que seria misturar muita coisa. Quebrei em duas perguntas.

Comment: Então, "ser para o mesmo fim" todas elas podem ser (ou não). Tem agências brasileiras desenvolvendo sites em Unity3D, sendo que ela foi inicialmente criada para jogos. A questão é que OpenGL e DirectX são bibliotecas para renderização gráfica, SDL é uma biblioteca de acesso a áudio, entrada de dados e renderização, e Unity3D é uma game engine completa (com emulação de física, animações, editor visual integrado, etc, etc, etc).

Comment: Tipo essa Unity3D está mais para um similar a engine do Unreal.

Comment: Sim, de fato é um concorrente do Unreal. Tem inúmeras outras opções (algumas *freeware*): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines

Comment: @LuizVieira muito maneiro, não cheguei a estudar essa parte de  engine, mas gostei muito desse link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A grande diferença é 2D vs. 3D!

A parte gráfica do SDL de dá uma API para fazer gráficos 2D, enquanto OpenGL te fornece tanto 2D como 3D.

Importante ressaltar o SDL também fornece diversas APIs para além de gráficos: audio, mouse, teclado, joystick, etc. Não sei dizer o mesmo para OpenGL (pois nunca utilizei), mas é muito comum vê-lo sendo utilizado com outros frameworks para as *coisas* que não são apenas gráficos (muito comum utilizar OpenAL para áudio por exemplo).

Outra coisa, enquanto a API do SDL não te dá funções para renderizar gráficos 3D, é possível utilizar OpenGL para essa parte juntamente do SDL.

## Mas qual caminho trilhar?

#### SDL

Se você está apenas começando a desenvolver jogos (é para jogos?) e (ainda) não tem em mente seguir carreira nessa área ou já utilizar uma engine famosa o melhor mesmo é SDL.

SDL é uma excelente escolha para ir entendo conceitos essenciais de desenvolvimento de jogos. A API é bem simples de entender e bem "crua", ou seja, a maior parte da lógica vai ficar por sua conta e daí vêm um grande aprendizado (como controle de *frame rate*, por exemplo).

Outro ponto positivo do SDL é que suporta também OpenGL; ou seja, quando estiver pronto para *partir para o 3D*, você vai ficar focado exatamente nisso (já que o resto você já aprendeu com SDL).

Bônus: SDL 2 suporta android!

#### OpenGL (e DirectX)

Já OpenGL é bem mais *denso* que SDL, são muitos conceitos e é um pouco mais complicado para chegar em um resultado *funcionando*. A grande vantagem é que te dará a oportunidade de trabalhar com as engines mais famosas.

Mas fica o aviso: se for apenas um hobby, pode ser um pouco desanimador começar com algo tão grande.

OpenGL é portável para sistemas operacionais Windows, Linux, Mac OS e a plataforma do PlayStation.

DirectX, sendo da Microsoft é especificamente voltado para Windows e sistemas paralelos como Windows Phone ou Xbox.

Siga esta trilha se pretende fazer jogos que necessitam de alta performance (3D principalmente). Ambas as API's oferecem uma camada de acesso ao hardware e tornam possível a programação especificamente para uma placa de vídeo (no caso dos Shaders HLSL e GLSL).

---

#### Unity

Coloque também em sua lista o [Unity](https://unity.com/)!

Conheço pouco (nada aliás) sobre o Unity, mas é notável como ele vendo crescendo ultimamente.

Exemplos recentes são o último jogo da Blizzard, [Hearthstone](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearthstone:_Heroes_of_Warcraft), que utiliza Unity e também a [compra pela Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/somasegar/microsoft-acquires-syntaxtree-creator-of-unityvs-plugin-for-visual-studio) do [UnityVS](http://unityvs.com/), que integra o Unity ao Visual Studio (antes esse plugin era pago mas agora vai ser de graça!).

Comment: Inclui o Unity, esse eu nem tinha ouvido falar. É para jogo sim, mas a nível de hobby mesmo.